# Android RecyclerView finding out first and last view on ItemDecoration

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Here is my scenario

- I have to add space on first and last item of Recycler View
- I am doing so using `ItemDecoration`

  ```
   recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {


      @Override
      public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
          int totalHeight = parent.getHeight();
          int viewHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.breadcrumb_btn_height);
          int padding = (totalHeight - viewHeight) / 2;
          //to position view on middle
          if (view.getTag() instanceof Integer) {
              int position = (int) view.getTag();
              if (position == 0) {
                  //first position
                  outRect.set(padding, padding, 0, padding);
              } else if (position == linearLayoutManager.getItemCount() - 1)   {
                  //last position
                  outRect.set(0, padding, padding, padding);
              } else {
                  outRect.set(0, padding, 0, padding);
              }
          }


      }
  });
  ```

  Here  I have
- `LinearLayoutManager` with `Horizontal Orientation`

  I am adding `position` tag on `RecyclerView Adapter` in the following manner

  ```
  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(BreadCrumbViewHolder holder, int position) {
  holder.setPosition(position);
  }
  ```

  Is there any other way to access `RecyclerView` first and last child on `ItemDecoration` so that later on removing and adding items won't have any problem.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

> Is there any other way to access RecyclerView first and last child on
>   ItemDecoration so that later on removing and adding items won't have
>   any problem.

Yes. You can achieve what you want only by implementing your own `ItemDecoration`.

To get the current item/child position:

```
int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
```

To get the number of items/childs:

```
int itemCount = state.getItemCount();
```

With this you can add a *space* on the first and last child of your `RecyclerView`.

---

Now changing your code for this approach you get:

```
@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);

    //your padding...

    final int itemPosition = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
    if (itemPosition == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
        return;
    }

    final int itemCount = state.getItemCount();

    /** first position */
    if (itemPosition == 0) {
        outRect.set(padding, padding, 0, padding);
    }
    /** last position */
    else if (itemCount > 0 && itemPosition == itemCount - 1) {
        outRect.set(0, padding, padding, padding);
    }
    /** positions between first and last */
    else {
        outRect.set(0, padding, 0, padding);
    }
}
```

---

**Bonus:** If you are looking to give padding to all items of the RecyclerView take a look at the *Gist* I've created: https://gist.github.com/ryanamaral/93b5bd95412baf85a81a

Comment: Awesome man. Thanks. Do do add `parent.getChildPosition(view)` instead of `parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view)`

Comment: @laaptu the getChildPosition method has been deprecated. The documentation says to use getChildAdapterPosition or getChildLayoutPosition.

Comment: In this case I believe you should use `getChildLayoutPosition(view)` in combination with `state.getItemCount()`, instead of `getChildAdapterPosition(view)`. They account for the positions in the current layout pass, which can be less recent than the positions in the adapter.

Comment: Would this add spacing to the first and last card every time you scroll?

Comment: I can't believe that 4 years later after original answer nobody spotted that this does not work in all cases. if you read the documentation for State.getItemCount() you'll see that newly added items are not reflected in this count. This means that your calculation for 'first' or 'last' position is wrong.

Comment: @ievgen The [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.State#getitemcount) don't really reflect your claim that "newly added items are not reflected in this count."  It *does* say that newly added items won't be reflected on the pre-layout pass, but they will be seen on the second layout pass.

Comment: You should use `layoutManager.itemCount` with `RecyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition()` or `state.itemCount` with `RecyclerView.getChildLayoutPosition()`