# How do I "Save State" of my Recyclerview ItemDecorations & Offsets?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView of items and a layoutManager that is of type StaggeredGridLayoutManager.  I was in an interesting situation, I wanted my items staggered to look like this:

[image]

but my views are all the same size, so they would not stagger.  To correct the problem I needed to add an offset at the start of the 2nd column.  Since I was also creating my own custom decorator class I figured the best way to accomplish this was to just add an offset for the first right column item in my list using the getItemsOffsets method.

[image]

Here is the relevant code for my decorator class:

```
public class StampListDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

...
@Override public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);
    // good example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29666598/android-recyclerview-finding-out-first-and-last-view-on-itemdecoration/30404499#30404499

    /**
     *  Special case.  Te first right side item in the list should have an extra 50% top
     *  offset so that these equal sized views are perfectly staggered.
     */
    if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 1) {

        /**
         *  We would normally do a outRect.top = view.getHeight()/2 to create a 50% top offset on the first right item in the list.
         *  However, problems would arise if we paused the app when the top right item was scrolled off screen.
         *  In this situation, when we re-inflated the recyclerview since the view was off screen
         *  Android would say the height of the view was zero.  So instead I added code that
         *  looked for the height of the top most view that was visible (and would therefore
         *  have a height.
         *
         *  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29463560/findfirstvisibleitempositions-doesnt-work-for-recycleview-android
         *  because as a staggeredGrid layout you have a special case first visible method
         *  findFirstVisibleItemPositions that returns an array of (notice the S on the end of
         *  the method name.
         */
        StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutMngr = ((StaggeredGridLayoutManager) parent.getLayoutManager());
        int firstVisibleItemPosition = layoutMngr.findFirstVisibleItemPositions(null)[0];

        int topPos = 0;
        try {
            topPos = parent.getChildAt(firstVisibleItemPosition).getMeasuredHeight()/2;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        outRect.set(0, topPos, 0, 0);
    } else {
        outRect.set(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

}
```

}

my problem is that these offsets are not getting saved to state when my activity pauses/resumes.  So when I switch to another app and switch back, the right column in my RecyclerView slides back to the top...and I lose my stagger.

Can someone show me how to save my offset state?  Where are offsets supposed to be saved?  I was assuming the LayoutManager would save this information, and I'm saving the LayoutManager state, but that does not seem to be working.

Comment: Running into a similar situation, did you ever come up with a solution for this?