# java.lang.ClassCastException android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, item-decoration

I am developing a new app and app crashes and getting following error from Logcat

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException
>   android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutParams
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.getChildViewHolderInt
>   (RecyclerView.java:4609)
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition
>   (RecyclerView.java:4628)
>   com.empowered.healo.ui.screens.favourite.FavouriteExercisesFragment$initList$1.getItemOffsets
>   (FavouriteExercisesFragment.kt:69)
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ItemDecoration.getItemOffsets
>   (RecyclerView.java:10521) com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
>   (ZygoteInit.java:1374)

below my FavoriteExercisesFragment.java file

```
class FavouriteExercisesFragment : BaseMvpFragment(), FavoriteExerciseView {



    val adapter: FavoriteExerciseAdapter by lazy {
        FavoriteExerciseAdapter(context!!)
    }
    val presenter: FavoriteExercisePresenter = FavoriteExercisePresenter(this)

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favorite_ex, container, false)
        return rootView
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        }
        initToolbar()
        initList()
        presenter.getFavoriteExercise()
    }

    private fun initList() {
        rvExercise.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        rvExercise.adapter = adapter
        val helper = ItemTouchHelper(object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(ItemTouchHelper.UP or ItemTouchHelper.DOWN, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
            override fun onMove(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Boolean {
                adapter.onItemMove(viewHolder.adapterPosition, target.adapterPosition)
                return true
            }

            override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
                val position = viewHolder.adapterPosition
                val item = adapter.data[position]
                adapter.onItemDismiss(viewHolder.adapterPosition)
                presenter.deleteFromFavorite(item, position)
                showEmptyData(adapter.data.isEmpty())

            }
        })

        rvExercise.addItemDecoration(object : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {
            override fun getItemOffsets(outRect: Rect, itemPosition: Int, parent: RecyclerView) {
                super.getItemOffsets(outRect,itemPosition, parent)
                val position = parent.getChildPosition(view!!)
                if (position == 0) {
                    outRect.top = 58.dp
                } else {
                    outRect.top = 0
                }

            }
        })
        helper.attachToRecyclerView(rvExercise)
        adapter.helper = helper
        adapter.actions = object : FavoriteExerciseAdapter.AdapterAction {
            override fun playExercise(exercise: Exercise) {
                val file = exercise.files.firstOrNull { it.mainFile }
                val uri = file?.getFile() ?: ""

                context?.startActivityFromCenter(VideoActivity.newInstance(context, uri), rootView, VideoActivity.REQUEST_CODE)
            }
        }
    }
    private fun initToolbar() {
        toolbar.setOnNavigateIconClickListener { router.exit() }
        toolbar.setOnToolIconClickListener { openNavDrawer() }
    }

    override fun setFavoriteExercises(exercises: ArrayList<Exercise>) {
        showEmptyData(exercises.isEmpty())
        adapter.addData(exercises)
    }

    override fun showDeleteMessage(item: Exercise, position: Int) {
        val snack = Snackbar.make(rootView, R.string.message_remove_from_favorite, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
        snack.setAction(R.string.action_undo) {
            presenter.addToFavorite(item)
            adapter.addItemOnPosition(item, position)
            showEmptyData(adapter.data.isEmpty())
        }
        snack.show()
    }

    private fun showEmptyData(show: Boolean) {
        tvEmpty.visibility = if (show) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
        emptyIcon.visibility = if (show) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    }
}
```

below FavoriteExerciseAdapter.kt

class FavoriteExerciseAdapter(val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter() {

```
var data: ArrayList<Exercise> = ArrayList()
var actions: AdapterAction? = null
var helper: ItemTouchHelper? = null

override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): FavoriteViewHolder =
        FavoriteViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_favorite_exercises, p0, true))

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: FavoriteViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = data[position]
    val preview = item.files.firstOrNull { !it.mainFile }
    if (preview != null)
        Glide.with(holder.itemView)
                .load(preview.getFile())
                .into(holder.mainImage)
    else holder.mainImage.setImageResource(0)
    holder.tvName.text = item.title?.getText
    holder.play.setOnClickListener {
        actions?.playExercise(item)
    }
    holder.drag.setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
        if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            helper?.startDrag(holder)
        }
        false
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int = data.size

class FavoriteViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val mainImage: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mainImage)
    val tvName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName)
    val play: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon_play)
    val drag: View = itemView.findViewById(R.id.drag)
}

fun addData(data: ArrayList<Exercise>) {
    this.data = data
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

fun addItemOnPosition(item: Exercise, position: Int) {
    data.add(position, item)
    notifyItemInserted(position)
}

fun onItemDismiss(position: Int) {
    data.removeAt(position)
    notifyItemRemoved(position)
}

fun onItemMove(fromPosition: Int, toPosition: Int): Boolean {
    if (fromPosition < toPosition) {
        for (i in fromPosition until toPosition) {
            Collections.swap(data, i, i + 1)
        }
    } else {
        for (i in fromPosition downTo toPosition + 1) {
            Collections.swap(data, i, i - 1)
        }
    }
    notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition)
    return true
}

interface AdapterAction {
    fun playExercise(exercise: Exercise)
}
```

}

I have tried following [Android RecyclerView finding out first and last view on ItemDecoration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29666598/android-recyclerview-finding-out-first-and-last-view-on-itemdecoration) did not fix problem

Comment: Try to set this - In your Adapter inside `onCreateViewHolder`  in `inflate()` change last argument to `true` which is `attachToRoot`. Post your Adapter code if not fix .

Comment: @Adm I did not understand where exactly

Comment: Add code for `FavoriteExerciseAdapter`

Comment: @Adm I have added adapter code can you check it